# LaTeX: Overlapping text in table

Tags: tables, line-breaking

I am making a large table for the appendix of my paper, only I have problems with overlapping columns. I have checked multiple posts however the solutions did not help to solve my problem. I hope you have any suggestions to fix it.

I make use of the following code:

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\footnotesize
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\rotatebox{90}{
\begin{tabular}{p{4cm}|p{4cm}|p{4cm}|p{4cm}|p{4cm}}
\hline
{\color[HTML]{000000} \textbf{Target group}}                                   & \textbf{First approach}                                                                           & \textbf{Second approach}                                                                                                                     & \textbf{Third approach}                                                                                       & \textbf{Fourth approach}                                                                                                                                         \\ \hline
\textbf{Rotterdam}                                                             &                                                                                                   &                                                                                                                                              &                                                                                                               &                                                                                                                                                                  \\
{\color[HTML]{000000} 17-24 year}                                              & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Letter in ‘jij-vorm’ with login code for digital\\ survey\end{tabular} & Letter with login code digital survey and paper survey                                                                                       & Reminder letter with login code for digital survey                                                            & Reminder card (only the men)                                                                                                                                     \\
24-65 year                                                                     & Letter with login code for digital survey                                                         & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Letter with login code digital\\ survey and paper survey\end{tabular}                                             & Reminder letter with login code for digital survey                                                            & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Reminder card (only the men of 24-35 year). \\ In the 6 target districts unannounced\\ telephone interviews (35-65 year)\end{tabular} \\
65+                                                                            & Letter with login code for digital survey                                                         & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Letter with login code digital\\ survey and paper survey\end{tabular}                                             & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Reminder letter with login code for digital survey and\\ paper survey\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}In the 6 target districts unannounced\\ telephone interviews\end{tabular}                                                             \\
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Turks 1st generation\\ 24-65 year\end{tabular}      & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Letter NL and Turks with login code for digital\\ survey\end{tabular}  & Letter NL and Turkish with login,code digital survey and paper survey NL and,Turkish translation                                             & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Reminder letter NL and Turks with login code for digital\\ survey\end{tabular}     & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Invitation for telephone\\ interview or interview at home\end{tabular}                                                                \\
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Turks 1st generation\\ 65+\end{tabular}             & Letter NL and Turks with login code for digital survey                                            & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Letter NL and Turkish with login code digital survey and\\ paper survey NL and Turkish\\ translation\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Letter NL and Turks with login code for digital\\ survey\end{tabular}              & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Invitation for telephone\\ interview or interview at home\end{tabular}                                                                \\
Moroccans 1st generation 24-65 year                                            & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Letter NL and Arabic with login code for digital\\ survey\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Letter NL and Arabic with login code digital survey and\\ paper survey\end{tabular}                               & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Invitation for telephone\\ interview or interview at home\end{tabular}             &                                                                                                                                                                  \\
Moroccans 1st,generation 65+                                                   & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Letter NL and Arabic with login code for digital\\ survey\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Letter NL and Arabic with login code digital survey and\\ paper survey\end{tabular}                               & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Invitation for telephone interview\\ or interview at home\end{tabular}             &                                                                                                                                                                  \\
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Surinamers 1st\\ generation 24-65 year\end{tabular} & Letter with login code for digital survey                                                         & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Letter with login code digital\\ survey and paper survey\end{tabular}                                             & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Invitation for telephone interview\\ or interview at home\end{tabular}             &                                                                                                                                                                  \\
Surinamers 1st,generation 65+                                                  & Letter with login code for digital survey                                                         & Letter with login code digital survey and paper survey                                                                                       & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Invitation for telephone interview\\ or interview at home\end{tabular}             &                                                                                                                                                                  \\
\textbf{Region Rijnmond excluding Rotterdam}                                   &                                                                                                   &                                                                                                                                              &                                                                                                               &                                                                                                                                                                  \\
17-24 year                                                                     & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Letter in ‘jij-vorm’ with login code for digital\\ survey\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Letter with login code digital\\ survey and paper survey\end{tabular}                                             & Reminder letter with login code for digital survey                                                            &                                                                                                                                                                  \\
24-65 year                                                                     & Letter with login code for digital survey                                                         & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Letter with login code digital\\ survey and paper survey\end{tabular}                                             & Reminder letter with login code for digital survey                                                            &                                                                                                                                                                  \\
65+                                                                            & Letter with login code for digital survey                                                         & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Letter with login code digital\\ survey and paper survey\end{tabular}                                             & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Reminder letter with login code for digital survey and\\ paper survey\end{tabular} &                                                                                                                                                                  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}
```

Which gives the following problem:

[image]

Help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution. It's simpler to use the `sidewaystable*` environment and `tabularx`.  I removed the vertical lines, replaced `\hline`s with the rules from `booktabs`, which have some vertical padding around them, and used some commands from `makecell`. Furthermore, as most cell contents are repetitive, I introduced some macros to simplify typing them:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twocolumn]{article}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage{lmodern}%
\usepackage{array, tabularx, caption, booktabs, makecell}%
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry} %
\usepackage{amsmath}%
\usepackage{rotating}%
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}%
\usepackage{ragged2e}%
\newcommand\nl{\newline}%
%% some abbreviations%
\def\interview{Invitation for telephone interview or interview at home}%
\newcommand\DS[1][]{Letter #1 with login code for digital survey}%
\newcommand\DSP[1][]{Letter #1 with login code digital survey and paper survey}%
\newcommand\RDS[1][]{Reminder letter #1 with login code for digital survey}%
\newcommand\RDSP[1][]{Reminder letter #1 with login code for digital survey and paper survey}%

\begin{document}%


\begin{sidewaystable*}%
  \footnotesize
  \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
  \setcellgapes{1ex}\makegapedcells
  \renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
  \renewcommand\theadalign{lc}%
  \caption{My caption} \label{my-label}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l*{4}{ >{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}}
    \toprule
    \thead{Target group} & \thead{First approach} & \thead{Second approach} & \thead{Third approach} & \thead{Fourth approach} \\%
    \midrule%
    \textbf{Rotterdam} \\%
    {17--24 year} & \DS[in ‘jij-vorm’] & \DSP & \RDS & Reminder card (only the men) \\%
    24--65 year & \DS & \DSP & \RDS & Reminder card (only the men of 24-35 year). In the 6 target districts unannounced telephone interviews (35--65 year) \\
    65\,$ + $ & \DS & \DSP & \RDSP & In the 6 target districts unannounced telephone interviews \\
    \makecell[tl]{Turks 1st generation & & & & \\ 24--65 year} & \DS[NL and Turks] & \DSP[NL and Turkish] NL and Turkish translation & \RDS[NL and Turks] & \interview \\
    \makecell[tl]{Turks 1st generation & & & & \\ 65\,$ + $} & \DS[NL and Turks] & \DSP[NL and Turkish] NL and Turkish translation & \DS[NL and Turks] & \interview \\
    \makecell[tl]{Moroccans 1st generation & & & & \\ 24--65 year} & \DS[NL and Arabic] & \DSP[NL and Arabic] & \interview & \\%
    \makecell[tl]{Moroccans 1st generation & & & & \\ 65\,$ + $} & \DS[NL and Arabic] & \DSP[NL and Arabic] & \interview & \\
    \makecell[tl]{Surinamers 1st generation & & & & \\ 24--65 year} & \DS & \DSP & \interview & \\
    \makecell[tl]{Surinamers 1st generation & & & & \\ 65\,$ + $} & \DS & \DSP & \interview & \\
    \addlinespace[3ex]
    \multicolumn{5}{l}{\textbf{Region Rijnmond excluding Rotterdam}} \\
    17--24 year & \DS[in ‘jij-vorm’] & \DSP & \RDS & \\
    24--65 year & \DS & \DSP & \RDS & \\
    65\,+ & \DS & \DSP & \RDSP & \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}%
\end{sidewaystable*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks exactly how I wanted, thanks @Bernard! I only have two errors occurring when I do use the code in my own file. `\usepackage{ragged2e}? ` and `\end{tabularx}?`. Is this because I need to download a file on my computer for ragged2e? Sorry for asking, but them I know I am on the right track

Comment: Which distribution do you have? For `tabularx`, what is the exact error message?

Comment: This is the exact error message `LaTex Error: Option clash for package color. 
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. 
Type H <return> for immediate help.
… 
l.52 \usepackage {ragged2e%}
?` and I use `documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}`, don't now if this makes it different

Comment: That's a minor error. You've loaded `xcolor` twice, and once with option `[table]`. Load it only once, preferably with the option (it loads `colortbl` then, useful if you want to colour some tables). For `ragged2e`, it's probably not installed on your system. Install it with your package manager. Are you under MiKTeX?

Comment: Great! No, never used it consciously. However, so far I am not able to download `ragged2e` on tex live, it is probably my mistake since I am quite new to R and not really handy with these things. Is there another way then using miktex or tex live to download `ragged2e`?

Comment: There's TeX Live Package Manager that  does the job. Installing by hand might be complex if you're not familiar with installing packages. What do you mean with `R`?

Comment: Oeps! R was a typo, I ment LaTeX. However, I tried to add ragged2e  in Tex Live Utility but did not succeed. I also searched how to download/find Tex Live Package Manager on my laptop but no success there either. Not sure what to do now, might include it as a picture instead of a table. In the beginning the program has quite a steep learning curve...  ;-)

Comment: If you use TeX Live Utility, I guess you're under MacTeX, right? It's the version of tlmgr adapted to MacOS. I've just checked: `ragged2e` does not exist as a package by itself. It's in a bunch of packages by Martin Schröder, `ms`. It's this one you should install.